# R programming Web Scraping

Tags: r, web-scraping

I tried to scrape webpage from the below link using R vest package from R programming.

The link that I scraped is http://dk.farnell.com/c/office-computer-networking-products/prl/results

My code is:

```
library("xml2")

library("rvest")

url<-read_html("http://dk.farnell.com/c/office-computer-networking-products/prl/results")

tbls_ls <- url %>%

html_nodes("table") %>%

html_table(fill = TRUE)%>%

gsub("^\\s\\n\\t+|\\s+$n+$t+$", "", .)

View(tbls_ls)
```

My requirement is that I want to remove `\\n,\\t` from the result.  I want to give pagination to scrape multiple pages, so that I can scrape this webpage with pagination.

Comment: Kindly read the site terms: http://dk.farnell.com/terms-of-access

Comment: Also... learn to spell `rvest` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm intrigued by these kinds of questions so I'll try to help you out.  Be forewarned, I am not an expert with this stuff (or anything close to it).  Anyway, I think it should be kind of like this...

```
library(rvest)
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

urls <- read_html("http://dk.farnell.com/c/office-computer-networking-products/prl/results/")
pag <- 1:5

read_urls <- paste0(urls, pag)
read_urls %>% 
  map(read_html) -> p
```

Now, I didn't see any '\\n' or '\\t' patterns in the data sets.  Nevertheless, if you want to look for a specific string, you can do it like this.

```
library(stringr)
str_which(urls, "[your]string_here")
```

The link below is very useful!

http://dept.stat.lsa.umich.edu/~jerrick/courses/stat701/notes/webscrape.html